# Google Visualization row 1 does not display .ColorFormat() when using .setProperty()

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I have applied this styling to column 1 of a simple table.

```
  var formatterDateCol = new google.visualization.ColorFormat();
  formatterDateCol.addRange(null, dtHigh, 'black', 'pink');
```

Any date older than the first day of the current month should come out pink.

Row 1 does not display `.ColorFormat()`  All other rows below this work fine.

`.ColorFormat()` works perfectly when I remove the following code which sets the column width.

```
data.setProperty(0, 0, 'style', 'width: 100px;');
```

Why is it doing this?  I appreciate any feedback on what I may have done mistakenly.  Thanks!!

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['table']
}).then(function() {

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Revenues');

  var dt1 = new Date(moment().endOf('month').subtract(3, 'month'));
  var dt2 = new Date(moment().endOf('month').subtract(2, 'month'));
  var dt3 = new Date(moment().endOf('month').subtract(1, 'month'));
  var dt4 = new Date(moment().startOf('month'));
  var dt5 = new Date(moment().startOf('month').add(1, 'day'));
  var dt6 = new Date(moment().startOf('month').add(2, 'day'));

  data.addRows([
    [dt1, 10700],
    [dt2, -15400],
    [dt3, 12500],
    [dt4, -2100],
    [dt5, 22600],
    [dt6, 1100],
    [dt1, 10700],
    [dt2, -15400],
    [dt3, 12500],
    [dt4, -2100],
    [dt5, 22600],
    [dt6, 1100],
  ]);

  var groupView = google.visualization.data.group(
    data, [0], [{
      column: 1,
      aggregation: google.visualization.data.sum,
      type: 'number'
    }]);


  var dtHigh = new Date(moment().startOf('month'));

  var formatterDateCol = new google.visualization.ColorFormat();
  formatterDateCol.addRange(null, dtHigh, 'black', 'pink');

  formatterDateCol.format(data, 0);
  formatterDateCol.format(groupView, 0);

  //COMMENTING setProperty OUT RESOLVES THE PROBLEM - BUT I NEED THE COLUMN WIDTH TO BE SET

  //Column Widths - (row, column)
  data.setProperty(0, 0, 'style', 'width: 100px;');
  groupView.setProperty(0, 0, 'style', 'width: 100px;');

  var options = {
    allowHtml: true,
    showRowNumber: true,
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%'
  };

  var table1 = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div1'));
  var table2 = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div2'));

  table1.draw(data, options);
  table2.draw(groupView, options);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
data - Row 1 does not display with ColorFormat. Row 7 contains the same date as Row 1 and it displays the ColorFormat.
<div id="table_div1"></div>

<p>
  <hr/>
</p>
groupView - Row 1 does not display with ColorFormat.
<div id="table_div2"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ColorFormat()` actually does the same thing,
it sets the style property on rows that should be highlighted.
as such, setting the width overrides the color format already applied.

if you used `getProperty`, you would see --> `"color:black;background-color:pink;"`

to fix, apply the color format, then use `getProperty` to retrieve the style it creates,
then combine that with the width, when using `setProperty`...

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['table']
}).then(function() {

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Revenues');

  var dt1 = new Date(moment().endOf('month').subtract(3, 'month'));
  var dt2 = new Date(moment().endOf('month').subtract(2, 'month'));
  var dt3 = new Date(moment().endOf('month').subtract(1, 'month'));
  var dt4 = new Date(moment().startOf('month'));
  var dt5 = new Date(moment().startOf('month').add(1, 'day'));
  var dt6 = new Date(moment().startOf('month').add(2, 'day'));

  data.addRows([
    [dt1, 10700],
    [dt2, -15400],
    [dt3, 12500],
    [dt4, -2100],
    [dt5, 22600],
    [dt6, 1100],
    [dt1, 10700],
    [dt2, -15400],
    [dt3, 12500],
    [dt4, -2100],
    [dt5, 22600],
    [dt6, 1100],
  ]);

  var groupView = google.visualization.data.group(
    data, [0], [{
      column: 1,
      aggregation: google.visualization.data.sum,
      type: 'number'
    }]);

  var dtHigh = new Date(moment().startOf('month'));

  var formatterDateCol = new google.visualization.ColorFormat();
  formatterDateCol.addRange(null, dtHigh, 'black', 'pink');

  formatterDateCol.format(data, 0);
  formatterDateCol.format(groupView, 0);

  //COMMENTING setProperty OUT RESOLVES THE PROBLEM - BUT I NEED THE COLUMN WIDTH TO BE SET

  //Column Widths - (row, column)
  var style = data.getProperty(0, 0, 'style');
  data.setProperty(0, 0, 'style', style + 'width: 100px;');
  var style = groupView.getProperty(0, 0, 'style');
  groupView.setProperty(0, 0, 'style', style + 'width: 100px;');

  console.log(JSON.stringify(data.getProperty(0, 0, 'style')));

  var options = {
    allowHtml: true,
    showRowNumber: true,
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%'
  };

  var table1 = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div1'));
  var table2 = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div2'));

  table1.draw(data, options);
  table2.draw(groupView, options);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
data - Row 1 does not display with ColorFormat. Row 7 contains the same date as Row 1 and it displays the ColorFormat.
<div id="table_div1"></div>

<p>
  <hr/>
</p>
groupView - Row 1 does not display with ColorFormat.
<div id="table_div2"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply!  As you suggested I set the width prior to the color format.  Can you check your example?  I think it's now lost the width in this order.

Comment: silly me, i was thinking google wouldn't override a style that already existed, changed answer above...

Comment: Worked perfectly this time!  I have implemented it in my project and life is good!  Time for the weekend and a beer.  Have a very nice weekend!